# select element base on its rel attribute with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="hello" rel="1"></div>
<div class="hello" rel="2"></div>
<div class="hello" rel="3"></div>

num = 3;
```

Why below selector doesn't work for me? I want to select hello class base on the element's custom attr.

```
var a = $('.hello[rel='+num+']');
```

Comment: Try using double quotes, like this `var a = $('.hello[rel="'+num+'"]');`.

Comment: any error showing in console? have you include jquery?
and is your num= 3 put inside <script> tag ?
see the example https://jsfiddle.net/xdzg9fLr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should enclose the value of the attribute in double quotes

```
var a = $('.hello[rel="'+num+'"]');
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNOQrw

As a side note for a matter of markup validation I would suggest to use a `data-*` attribute instead, since `rel` is an attribute for [link elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-link-rel)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log($('.hello[rel=1]'));
```

Over all code should look like this:

```js
var num  = 3;
var a = $('.hello[rel='+num+']');
alert($(a).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hello" rel="1">1</div>
<div class="hello" rel="2">2</div>
<div class="hello" rel="3">3</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 var a = $('.hello[rel="'+num+'"]');
```

this will help you

Comment: Don't you think doing this will actually assign the attribute value rather fetching .?